# Data not shown in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a list of items with a Recycler View in a simple way by making a method called `Data()` that's has a for loop to set the text view continuously but when I run the app it show's me a white screen without anything.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerAdapter mAdapter ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView =(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

    private class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder{ 

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
            MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {    
           holder.Data();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 100;
        }
    }

    private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView mmTextView ;
        private Button mButton;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mmTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list_text_view);
            mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.list_button);
        }

        private void Data (){
            for (int i =0 ;i<=100;i++){
                mmTextView.setText(String.valueOf("Text : " + i));
            }    
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are currently adding 100 text strings to EVERY holder (each of which is supposed to hold only one set of your `TextView` and `Button`combination.

Comment: Yes, what KalaBalik says is true. You are trying to set each view of Holder 101 times, for total 100 views, but you are not assaigning textviews to Holder and it does not work.

Comment: you might want to review how a recyclerview adapter works, dude. https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 0):

You should infilate `mmTextView` from itemView not from `Activity`. It should be `mmTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_text_view);`, also since it's a view of holder you can get it in `onBindViewHolder()` method using `holder.mmTextView.setText()`. Infilate button on onCreate() of Activity, also it's convenient to pass data to an adapter inside it's constructor and bind data to adapter on `onBindViewHolder()` method since it knows which views it possesses.

Answer (score 0):

In onBindViewHolder method bind the data into the textView:

```
mmTextView.mmTextView.setText("SOME STRING VALUE");
```

Comment: You don't inflate views onBindViewHolder(), you bind data to views of holder you infilate inside constructor of public MyViewHolder(View itemView) { mmTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_text_view);} then you can use it as holder.mmTextView inside onBindViewHolder() method.